# Spark Custom Receiver to access Cassandra wired using Spring Boot

Tags: apache-spark, spring-boot

I am trying to write a Spark Java Custom Receiver and within the receiver I need to access a Cassandra database. I have the Spark running in cluster mode with at least 2 workers.

Here is my **Java Custom Spark Receiver**

```
@Service
public class MyCustomReceiver extends Receiver<MyData>{

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyCustomReceiver.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyAppConfig myAppConfig;

    @Autowired
    private CassandraDataService cassandraDataService;

    public MyCustomReceiver() {
        super(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2());
        logger.debug("Initiated...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // Start the thread that receives data over a connection
        logger.debug("Calling the receive method...");
        receive();
        logger.debug("Done.. calling the receive method...");
    }

    private void receive() {
        logger.debug("receive method called...");

        List<String> myConfigs = myAppConfig.getMyConfig();
        logger.debug("Received myConfigs..." + myConfigs);

        for(String myConfigStr : myConfigs)
        {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            MyConfig myConfig;

            try {

                while (!isStopped()) {

                    myConfig = mapper.readValue(myConfigStr, MyConfig.class);

                    logger.debug("Parsed the myConfig..." + myConfig);

                    // Check for matching data in Cassandra
                    List<MyData> cassandraRows = cassandraDataService.getMatches(myConfig);

                    for(MyData myData : cassandraRows)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Received data '" + myData + "'");
                    }

                    store(cassandraRows.iterator());
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

    }
}
```

**Spark Application / Driver Program -**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootSparkApp {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MySpringBootSparkApp.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("Initiated MySpringBootSparkApp...");

        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootSparkApp.class, args);
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Processing Boot App");
        JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(1000));
        JavaReceiverInputDStream<MyData> myDataDStream = jsc.receiverStream(
                new MyCustomReceiver());
        myDataDStream.foreachRDD(myDataJavaRDD -> {
            logger.debug("myDataJavaRDD = " + myDataJavaRDD);
            myDataJavaRDD.foreach(myData -> {
                System.out.println("myData = " + myData);
            });
        });
    } 
}
```

When I submit the uber jar with the above app and all the dependencies to the  cluster with at least 2 worker nodes, I see that the Driver program is picked up by one worker and the Custom Receiver processing starts. The logs do not show if there is anything else happening - like the Custom Receiver being invoked, is fetching data from Cassandra or if the data being returned to the Driver.

here is the log4j.properties from the Spark Conf directory -

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, console    
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender    
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err    
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout    
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n    

# Set the default spark-shell log level to WARN. When running the spark-shell, the    
# log level for this class is used to overwrite the root logger's log level, so that    
# the user can have different defaults for the shell and regular Spark apps.    
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=DEBUG    

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose    
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty=WARN    
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR    
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO    
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO    
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR    
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR    

# SPARK-9183: Settings to avoid annoying messages when looking up nonexistent UDFs in SparkSQL with Hive support    
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler=FATAL    
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry=ERROR
```

I am not sure how else I can figure out what is going on with the above code and why the MyData records that I am expecting to be returned by the Receiver are never printed in the Spark Main Program at all and I cannot deduce if it is being returned at all or not. Any guidance on how to proceed will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out... 
I did not call the start() on the JavaStreamingContext

```
jsc.start();
jsc.awaitTermination();
```

Once I did this, the whole Java App started giving me what I am looking for. Cheers!